# Nativescript - clearing a gesture event

Tags: nativescript

I'm setting a gesture callback as follows:

```
observer = layout.on(gestures.GestureTypes.swipe, function (args:  gestures.SwipeGestureEventData)
{
    console.log("Swipe dir=" + args.direction );
});
```

This is being done in the page loaded event.

However, the returned observer value is `undefined`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can directly stop observing the swipe event for your `layout`

```
layout.on("swipe", (args:  gestures.SwipeGestureEventData) => {
    console.log("Swipe dir = " + args.direction );
});

...

layout.off("swipe");
```